# Not receiving the email traceback Django on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have an application and some pages are giving internal server error. I configured the environment variables in Heroku (`heroku config:add <variable=value>`) and I can not get the traceback via email. My settings.py are in production with `DEBUG = False`, and settings_local.py `DEBUG = True`

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Name <email@gmail.com>'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get ('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get ('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

`EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` variables are programmed into the Heroku environment, however, even when access a page that I know will give error, not get anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your name and mail into `ADMINS` in `settings.py`.

```
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
```

Comment: My name is already there when I saw that I was not returning the email, I decided to try this solution